# What is the best way to visualize hybridization

Tags: hybridization, valence-bond-theory

I had learnt hybridization in various complex definitions some of them as "complex overlapping of orbitals (in quantum mechanical model) which leads in changing of shape of orbitals itself.
But these definitions hardly make any sense without understanding it intuitively...
So what is best way to understand this intuitively ?

Comment: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/wPw_LCmyjnI)

Comment: What it worked for me was that given the valence, ie how many bond orbitals shall form, the hybrid ones allow for a more symmetric distribution of electrons and less repulsion and thus an overall lower energy. But I think it is the way that every teacher uses at basic level (by the way, for once a simple description that is accurate).

Comment: Hybridisation is a mathematical model. You take the shape of the molecule, then you arrange the orbitals by linear combination to get to that shape. There is nothing intuitive about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in thinking about *hybridisation* in the sense of a process, where orbitals "change" their form.

You have the basic (atomic) orbitals, and (atoms in) compounds additionally have "hybrid" orbitals. They are called "hybrid" because you can mathematically model them relatively accurately by combining atomic orbitals. To use those "sp", "sp2", .. to describe bonding, you don't have to worry what their wave function looks like, you just remember their geometry.

To form a bond, you anyway have to combine the orbital with one from the other atom. $sp^x$ just tells you what it looks like on one side.